# Form validation - group OR condition

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I have form with three element - name, login and email. In `validation.yml` I have:

```
Mark\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
        login:
            - NotBlank: ~
        email:
            - Email: ~
            - NotBlank: ~
```

It works, this makes `name` and `login` required. Instead, I need `name` or `login` required. `email` remains always required.

In Symfony 1.4 I can use [sfValidatorOr](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/forms/1_4/en/B-Validators#chapter_b_sub_sfvalidatoror). How can I make it in Symfony 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should solve this by using the `Callback` constraint instead:

```
// ...
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContextInterface;

class User
{
    // ...

    public function hasCorrectCreditials(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        $isBlank = function ($val) {
            return null === $this->name || '' === $this->name;
        };

        if ($isBlank($this->name)) {
            if ($isBlank($this->login)) {
                $context->addViolationAdd('login', 'Either name or login should not be blank');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```yaml
Mark\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    constraints:
        - Callback: { methods: [hasCorrectCreditials] }
    properties:
        email:
            - Email: ~
            - NotBlank: ~
```